# Operation timed out running Drupal/Civi on MAMP

Tags: mamp

I'm trying to make a local copy of our site in MAMP to play around with, but it's really, really slow. Extraordinarily slow. So slow, in fact, that the database connection seems to be timing out.

The Drupal pages and admin area mostly seem to load OK, except for the following error appended to the bottom of the homepage:

```
Initialization Error

Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => simpleHandler
        )

    [code] => -24
    [message] => DB Error: connect failed
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] =>  [nativecode=Operation timed out]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] =>  [nativecode=Operation timed out]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: connect failed" code=-24 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info=" [nativecode=Operation timed out]"]
)
```

When I click the CiviCRM link that would normally take me through to the CiviCRM homepage, I get just that same error on a white background.

MAMP's WebStart page, PHPinfo and phpMyAdmin all seem to run just fine. I'm using a completely bog standard default MAMP config, with the site on localhost:8888, no custom locations. The only change I've made is to increase the PHP memory_limit to 512M.

MAMP 5.5, PHP 7.3.8, mySQL 5.7.26, Drupal 7.67, CiviCRM 5.18.4

Comment: I do think this might be something to do with the MySQL configuration and not the PHP configuration.

Comment: It does look like it's timing out waiting for a response from MySQL. Any idea what might cause it?

Comment: Not really as I am not an expert in Mysql configuration.